# To check if a string of words is a sentence

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, spacy, data-extraction

I have a text file from which I have to eliminate all the statements which do not make any meaning or in other words, I have to check for a statement that if it is a sentence or not.

For example:

```
1. John is a heart patient.
2. Dr. Green, Rob is the referring doctor for the patient.
3. Jacob Thomas, M.D. is the ordering provider

4. Xray Shoulder PA, Oblique, TRUE Lateral, 18° FOSSA LAT LT; Status: Complete;
```

The sentence 1,2, ad 3 makes some meaning
but sentence 4 does not make any meaning, so I want to eliminate it.

May I know how it could be done?

Answer (score 1):

This task seems very difficult; however, assuming you have the training data, you could likely use [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which uses boosted decision trees (and random forests). You would train it to answer positive or negative (yes is makes sense, or no).

You would then need to come up with features. You could use the features from the [NLTK part of speech (POS) tags](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html). The number of occurrences  of each of the types of tags in the sentence would be a good first model. That can set your benchmark for how good an "easy" solution is.

You also may be able to look into the utility of a (word/sentence)-to-vector model such as [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) for creating features for your model.

First I would see what happens with just the number of occurrences of each POS tag and XGBOOST. Train and test a model and see how well it does. Then look to adding other features such as position or using a doc-2-vec as your input to XGBoost.

Last resort would be a neural network (which would only be recommended if the prior ideas fail, and you have lots and lots of data). If you did use a neural net I would think an [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) would likely be useful.

You would have to experiment and the amount of data matters, but you can start simple and then test and add to your model iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to be 100% confident but let's try.

I can use Amazon Comprehend - Natural Language Processing and Text Analytics and create your own metrics over the sentences. ex:

John is a heart patient.
Amazon will give you: "." Punctuation, "a" Determiner, "heart" Noun, "is" verb, "John" Proper Noun, "patient" Noun. 
1 Punctuation, 1 Determiner, 2 **Noun**, 1 **Verb**, 1 Proper Noun.  Probably you will have Noun and verd to have a valid sentence.

In Your last sentence we have:
3 Punctuation, 1 Numeral, 11 Proper noun.  You dont have a action (verb) probably  these sentense isn't valid.

Comment: let me try this method using Spacy. If it gets successful, I will thank you very much
evinoshea: i will try your suggested solution as well.